# Large number of Java Native Query records cause Exception after 5 minutes. javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException

Tags: jakarta-ee

I researched the community but found nothing about it. I need to return to a Java List the result of a select query of 196,000 records.
As preferentially they are not letting us use Resultsets I am forced to use EntityManager.createNativeQuery();
but this error always returns me:
EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back

Hints:

1. I must to retrieve all the 196,000 records;

2. The Query is returned to a List Object;
`List<Object> lista = query.getResultList();`

3. After 5 minutes the Eclipse IDE returns that:

`throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException,java.sql.SQLException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:137)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:117)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:279)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)`


4. I'm using wildfly Jboss 10.x

5. I'm not using Mapped Query, just a native query.


Does anyone have some trick?
Thanks.

i've tried to increase JBoss wildfly memory, but it does not works.
In the standalone.conf I changed: 
AVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

```java
List<Object> lista = query.getResultList();`
```

I would expect to load the 196000 records to Java List but gives me the error EJB transaction exception.

Comment: Are you hitting 5 min timeout? How long does that query take with some SQL query tool?

Comment: Hi, it takes 2 minutes on PLSQL. I'm checking the real java time. One moment.

Comment: Ok Java delays just 3 minutes!
it's very difucul for me discover the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the solution was to increase Default timeout.

Just acess
(http://localhost:9990/console/App.html#profile/transactions)

Go to:
Configuration: Subsystems    Subsystem: Transactions Back |  >> Default timeout.

Regards from Brazil